# DD-WRT No Internet connection over LAN

Tags: internet-connection, lan, dd-wrt

FINAL UPDATE: **IT WORKS NOW**

*Kovica's original idea did proove to be right. I used "Win7 MAC Adress Changer", to generate a new random MAC address and it instantly worked. This does seem to be an issue with DD-WRT, because with the original firmware the MAC-cloning didn't prove to be an issue.*

---

I flashed the DD-WRT firmware on my TP-Link WR1043ND router and although after cloning the PC's MAC-Address it gets the correct IP from my ISP, the **internet connection over LAN just won't work.**

The strange thing is it does work flawlessly over W-LAN, which tells me the problem should lie somehow in the default LAN settings or the PC.

Any idea what the problem might be?

UPDATE: It seems the problem is the desktop PC, since the laptop can connect to the interet via ethernet without any problems. ipconfig /all seems totally normal (dhcp, dns, gateway all set to 192.168.1.1)

I already tried the following things without success:

- disabling firewall
- rebooting router/modem/pc
- router hard-reset
- resetting tcp/ip and winsock
- manual setting of DNS/IP/Gateway

Here is the **ipconfig /all**:

```
Windows-IP-Konfiguration

   Hostname  . . . . . . . . . . . . : Nitro-PC
   Primäres DNS-Suffix . . . . . . . : 
   Knotentyp . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP-Routing aktiviert  . . . . . . : Nein
   WINS-Proxy aktiviert  . . . . . . : Nein

Ethernet-Adapter LAN-Verbindung 2:

   Medienstatus. . . . . . . . . . . : Medium getrennt
   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix: 
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Win32 Adapter V9
   Physikalische Adresse . . . . . . : 00-FF-56-CA-66-8D
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Ja
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja

Ethernet-Adapter LAN-Verbindung:

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix: 
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physikalische Adresse . . . . . . : 48-5B-39-5B-DE-17
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Ja
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja
   Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse  . : fe80::6934:b121:9eab:c6ce%10(Bevorzugt) 
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.18(Bevorzugt) 
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease erhalten. . . . . . . . . . : Donnerstag, 30. August 2012 10:52:30
   Lease läuft ab. . . . . . . . . . : Freitag, 31. August 2012 10:52:30
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP-Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6-IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 239622969
   DHCPv6-Client-DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-17-43-0D-B2-48-5B-39-5B-DE-17
   DNS-Server  . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS über TCP/IP . . . . . . . : Aktiviert

Tunneladapter isatap.{56CA668D-9112-4399-9D9A-F1D42F0E52DE}:

   Medienstatus. . . . . . . . . . . : Medium getrennt
   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix: 
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft-ISATAP-Adapter
   Physikalische Adresse . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Nein
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja

Tunneladapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix: 
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physikalische Adresse . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Nein
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja
   IPv6-Adresse. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fd:1432:3dcd:3f57:feed(Bevorzugt) 
   Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse  . : fe80::1432:3dcd:3f57:feed%12(Bevorzugt) 
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   NetBIOS über TCP/IP . . . . . . . : Deaktiviert

Tunneladapter isatap.{AD21069D-D2AF-423E-BF59-0B1CD0D235E8}:

   Medienstatus. . . . . . . . . . . : Medium getrennt
   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix: 
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft-ISATAP-Adapter #2
   Physikalische Adresse . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Nein
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja

Tunneladapter 6TO4 Adapter:

   Medienstatus. . . . . . . . . . . : Medium getrennt
   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix: 
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft-6zu4-Adapter
   Physikalische Adresse . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Nein
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja
```

**route PRINT**

```
IPv4-Routentabelle
===========================================================================
Aktive Routen:
     Netzwerkziel    Netzwerkmaske          Gateway    Schnittstelle Metrik
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.18     10
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0   Auf Verbindung      192.168.1.18    266
     192.168.1.18  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung      192.168.1.18    266
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung      192.168.1.18    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung      192.168.1.18    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung      192.168.1.18    266
===========================================================================
Stndige Routen:
  Keine
```

Comment: Maybe your LAN internet is using the same ip address area like 192.168.1.* as your dd-wrt's LAN which leads to confliction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the problem lies in the fact that now two machine have the same MAC address and your PC does not get the settings over DHCP.

Comment: Well I am not an expert in networking myself but it seems the router only has copied the PC's MAC address as its new WAN MAC Address and kept its own MAC for LAN/W-LAN.

edit: It also seems that DHCP is working correctly, since I can manage the router, ping other devices in the network, etc.

Comment: try running "tracert www.google.com". If you don't get back anything then you don't have your DNS configured. Try "ping 173.194.35.176" and if you don't get back anything then the you are not connected to the internet. so your WAN link is not working. For DNS you can use 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4. Those two are from Google. And the IP in ping is also Google.

Comment: But I still think that your router and your PC have to have different MAC addresses

Comment: I disagree with most of your points.
As I said they do have different MAC addresses on the LAN. DHCP/Network etc. are working but the internet connection just won't work unless directly plugged into the modem. And my WAN link also works since I have internet over WLAN and the laptop can also connect via Ethernet. It's apparently just the PC :(

Comment: If you put it that way, then yes. PC is the problem. Try running ipconfig, route print to see how everything is configured.

Comment: updated the post with my ipconfig and the route print. Don't see anything wrong there though.

Comment: Hi the MAC address apparently was the problem all along. (Although not really because of DHCP). It's just strange because the router and my PC says that the router LAN MAC address isn't the same as the PC, so there probably is an issue in the DD-WRT firmware.